# the best way to model objects in a game

Tags: java, game-physics

I 'm trying to recreate a game similar to **fruiitNinja** in java for a project , I would like advice on these questions :

- how to represent the world ? **or** is it correct to represent the world in a game like  this?

  - This type of game is different than a side- scroller game or a platformer game , where the world can be expressed by:

    1. **A matrix of integers** that assigns to a specific location represented by an integer, an object of the game .
    2. **A matrix of tile blocks** (i think this way is best for a platformer game) , where the blocks are objects of the game.In this case block could be represented as fruits.

of course I could use one of these two solutions, however, does not seem right to me , Because fruitNinja has not placed objects in the world.
in theory the only object placed statically in the world is the player's life

- how to represent the fruits ?

  - I would have thought at first to an `arrayList <GenericFruit>` ,where I post any kind of fruit that I Instantiate inside game

  or

  - Various types of `arrayList<fruit1>` , `arrayList <fruit2>` .....

for both solutions , for example, if I finish slide the arrayList, I can understand that the user has cut all the fruits available , and I flow randomly again the entire array,

**if you think this is a good idea,  can you tell me a data structure powerful enough to handle?**
because I think it's pretty heavy load the array of continuously

Comment: Every fruit should implement an interface with methods which are important to you, therefore you can store them in `List<FruitInterface>` and then updating them all at once easily.

Comment: Use a matrix of tile block fruits, and List<FruitInterface>.